# How to give access Service Desk Customers to JIRA project?

Tags: jira

I have two projects in JIRA: software project and service desk project.
My goal it to enable my service desk customers to access the software project but in a limited way. E.g.:

- clients could create stories,
- comment on them,
- assign priorities
- and assist with assigning them to iterations / releases.

But they would not be able to perform and see some actions e.g.:

- see the logged time
- and ideally to keep some of the ticket / story fields and comments as internal use only so I can have technical discussions with my team without the client seeing them etc.

I can see in documentation that "Service Desk Customers can't log in to JIRA applications":
https://confluence.atlassian.com/servicedeskcloud/setting-up-service-desk-users-732528877.html

But is there any workaround to give Service Desk Customers access to JIRA applications? Is there any simpler method than making a REST API bind? If yes, then how it could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not clear. Add their accounts to the jira-users group and they will be able to log into JIRA as regular users. The point is that member of jira-users consumes a JIRA user license, while "pure" customer account does not.

As regular regular users they will have permissions just as you configure your project Permission Scheme, so everything is in your hands. Using roles you can restrict issue comments to those roles. There's also nice [Comment Security Default](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.redmoon.jira.comment-security-default/server/overview) plugin to use with that.